# Display submitted information in the Form PHP

Tags: php

I need to display submitted information in the form which will automatically display the information in the same page.How can I write it right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the form to submit to the same page and print out the submitted data?

Comment: First try it yourself, we won't write an entire code for you

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST);` just to show what the user posted. Use ajax to dynamically show new information on the page.

Comment: try `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly what you're trying to do from your question as it stands now. Try to do something and when you get stuck at some exact problem, come back and ask. P.S. You'll find answer on almost every basic question at http://php.net/

Comment: I have done something, but it is not exactly what I need the code is too large to display it here. I need just the part when  the submitted information shows on the same page in the other form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use print_r() function clubbed with AJAX

Comment: dpk2442 Yep, I need it to be shown on the same page

Comment: Sorry for referencing w3schools, but here's an example to get you started http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2